# Getting Observable value before executing function in Angular2

Tags: angular, firebase, observable

I have a simple simple system with a user authentication system from Firebase. I want to receive a list of data for the user currently logged in. I get the information from the currently logged in user by subscribing to an observable from Firebase.

However, the value of `private authId` which is set in my constructor is not called before the `getAllEmails()` function is called. Therefore the `${this.authId}` yields undefined. How can I make sure that I have the value of authId ready from the observable before my `getAllEmails` function is called?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2';
import { Email } from '../email';
import { AuthService } from '../auth/auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class EmailService {

  private authId: string;

  constructor(
    private af: AngularFire,
    private authService: AuthService
  ) {
    this.authService.getUserInformation()
      .subscribe(user => {
        this.authId = user.authId;
      })
  }    

  getAllEmails(): FirebaseListObservable<any> {
    return this.af.database.list(`/emails/${this.authId}`);
  }

}
```

Comment: where are you calling getAllEmails()? ngOnInit()

Comment: Yep, and then assigning it to a class variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of things you can do for this

1. create a base service class and get authId in the constructor of base class
2. get the authId in the constructor of Component and call getAllEmails(authId)

the solution is below:

```
export class baseService{

private authId: string;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    this.authService.getUserInformation()
      .subscribe(user => {
        this.authId = user.authId;
      })
  }
getAuthId(): number{
       return this.authId;
}
}

import {baseService} from '<yourPath>'

@Injectable()
export class EmailService extends baseService {

  private authId: string;

  constructor(private af: AngularFire) {  }    

  getAllEmails(): FirebaseListObservable<any> {
    return this.af.database.list('/emails/'+ super.getAuthId());
  }

}
```

2nd Solution would be:

instead of base class have another service class to get AuthId in controller and pass it. I think first solution is a little better.

Comment: Thanks for that. However, it seems that you've omitted the super() call in the EmailService. How would that look? When I try to do super(authService) I get an error

Comment: Kamran, do you know what the best setup for making the super() call would be with your setup?

Comment: i just gave a suggestion please have a look at typescript docs for calling base class methods